# AnnotationSessionFactoryBean requires lucene classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to add transaction support to an existing webapp via spring transactions.

I recently changed my session factory class from LocalSessionFactoryBean to AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.

now I get the following error when the webapp starts:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

so the root cause it

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
```

I don't understand why now I need to include lucene in my webapp. I don't plan to use it for search and it seems very wrong to me that this error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the full strack trace, I can't be sure, but my guess is that this has something to do with Hibernate Search, which uses Lucene under the hood.

The `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` will attempt to auto-detect the presense of Hibernate Search on the classpath, and will initialize it if it's found. Dependening on your environment, it may get so far before failing to find Lucene.

Have a grub around on your classpath, see if Hibernate Search is there, and see if you can remove it. Another option is to set the `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` hibernate property to `false`, which should explicitly disable the registration of Hibernate Search.